# Pasting cell range from MS Excel into MS PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm using below code to paste cell range in Excel as image into PowerPoint.

```
xlApp.Worksheets(5).Range("B2:D9").Copy
Set shp1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)(1)

With shp1
' Set position:
.Left = 22
.Top = 95
' Set size:
.Height = 250
.Width = 280
End With
```

But image is not being pasted as of defined size, i.e. height 250 and width 280. As per my understanding, it considers aspect ratio of the image while pasting and does not distort it. But I don't want that. I just want it to cover the entire area I want on PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch off **aspectratio parameter** before you set widht and height:

```
With shp1
' Set position:
.Left = 22
.Top = 95
' Set size:
.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
.Height = 250
.Width = 280
End With
```

Comment: @crazyfrog, you're welcome... and don't forget to mark the answer as a correct one.

Comment: Done.... If I may extend my question a little bit... Like for specified excel range in my code, there is a table in MS Excel. Now what I want is to copy it and paste it as an editable table in MS PowerPoint. How would I change my code for PasteSpecial?

Comment: try to set lasta parameter of [`.PasteSpecial method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff745158(v=office.14).aspx) to `true`.

Comment: Actually it is allowing me to change the data, but by taking me to the source excel file. I want it to allow me to change the data in PowerPoint table itself (without opening excel file). Moreover, it is creating a link between excel and ppt, which I do not want.

Comment: Set shp1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteOLEObject, , , , , False)(1)